# Ant Better way to <sleep> instead of skipping it

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I am adding more than 20 files to a fileset with various includes and excludes file. This takes a bit so the dependent task on Ant fileset is skipped by Ant. It wont run the dependent operation at all. This is inefficient. Does anyone know a better way to make the fileset to add files and then perform dependent instead of skipping it?

A way to do that is to use sleep https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sleep.html. I cannot use waitfor.

**Example:**

```
<fileset id="scr" dir="dir1/*" casesensitive="yes"
           includes="bin/*, lib/*  excludes="dir1/*.py />

    <foreach param="file" in="scr">
             <echo message="${file}"/>                      
    </foreach>
</fileset>
```

The above example will skip printing the file name completely since Ant is still adding files to fileset.

Answer (score 2):

The foreach task is not part of ANT, it is a 3rd party extension and I'm not entirely certain it's designed to work the way you think.

Instead could I suggest you print your fileset contents as follows:

```
<apply executable="echo">
  <fileset dir="dir1/*" casesensitive="yes" includes="bin/*, lib/*  excludes="dir1/*.py />
</apply>
```

Or like this if you want to use a fileset reference:

```
<fileset id="scr" dir="dir1/*" casesensitive="yes" includes="bin/*, lib/*  excludes="dir1/*.py />

<apply executable="echo">
  <fileset refid="scr"/>
</apply>
```

Note:

- Ant is not a programming language so looping is not fun. If you need complex logic I highly recommend embedding a scripting language. I don't recommend ant-contrib

Comment: I am doing more than printing in for each and what you suggested is to use fileset and Echo it but honestly the problem is that fileset takes a while to process so I am using sleep so will apply help make the ant to wait and be Able to print echo once fileset has been processed?

Comment: @fscore I don't think it's working quite like you're describing. The apply task is designed to operate on each file in the fileset. I would suggest using that and stop using the foreach task which is not part of core ANT.

Comment: would `apply` task wait for all files to be added to fileset and then do a echo?

Comment: @fscore The "apply" task will act on each file in the fileset. Constructing a fileset containing 20 files should be very fast.